# Borrar registro en tabla con relacion mucho a mucho EF 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Estoy intentando eliminar un registro de una tabla intermedia, es decir, de una tabla con una relación de mucho a muchos. Me gustaría saber cómo puedo eliminar un registro de dicha tabla ya que cuando intento salvar el registro no me presenta error, pero el registro no se elimina. La estructura que tengo es la siguiente:

Tablas

- PERFIL (ID_PERFIL, DESCRIPCION, ESTADO)
- APLICACIONES (ID_APLICACION, DESCRIPCION, ESTADO)
- PERFIL_APLICACIONES (ID_APLICACION, ID_PERFIL)

Antes de usar entity lo que hacía era que antes de insertar en la tabla intermedia, eliminaba todo lo que había en la tabla PERFIL_APLICACIONES y luego volvía a insertar con los nuevos registros que tengo (dicho registro los tengo en un datagridview, donde el usuario puede agregar y eliminar y al final salvar en la base de datos).

Me gustaría saber si existe la manera de poder borrar la tabla intermedia sin tener que recorrer la entidad, es decir, sin hacer un foreach.

Este es mi codigo:

```
if (dgvAplicacion.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvAplicacion.Rows)
    {
        var idapl = row.Cells["ID_APLICACION"].Value.ToString();
        perfil.AM_PERFIL_TBL.Find(id).AM_APLICACIONES_TBL.Add(perfil.AM_APLICACIONES_TBL.Find(idapl));
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos lo que has intentado?

Comment: Encontre una solucion, la cual consiste en eliminar todo de la tabla intermedia y luego insertar nueva vez. perfil.AM_PERFIL_TBL.Find(id).AM_APLICACIONES_TBL.Clear(); no se si sea correcto

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro que hayas encontrado la respuesta por ti mismo. Que tal si respondes la pregunta para los demás en caso de que les pase lo mismo? Y recuerda marcar la respuesta como la elegida.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno no se si sea la mejor opcion la que he utilizado, pero lo hize tal como hacia antes de usar entity, elimino primero la tabla intermedia y luego inserto los registro de la siguiente manera:

```
if (dgvAplicacion.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   //esta es la linea que he agregado para eliminar los registro
   perfil.AM_PERFIL_TBL.Find(id).AM_APLICACIONES_TBL.Clear();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvAplicacion.Rows)
    {
        var idapl = row.Cells["ID_APLICACION"].Value.ToString();
        perfil.AM_PERFIL_TBL.Find(id).AM_APLICACIONES_TBL.Add(perfil.AM_APLICACIONES_TBL.Find(idapl));
    }
}
```

En caso se tener una mejor y mas factible forma estare agradecido